# Find if $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x\cdot\cos\left(7x\right)}{x^{2}+2x+2}$ converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

Find if $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x\cdot\cos\left(7x\right)}{x^{2}+2x+2}$ converges or diverges
I've already tried substituting cos(7x) for x. Still that gave me nore sult and I'm lost

Answer (score 1):

You can use integration by parts, namely:
$$
\int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac{x\cos{(7x)}}{x^2+2x+2}{\rm d}x=\left.\frac{1}{7}\frac{x\sin{(7x)}}{x^2+2x+2}\right|_{0}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{7}\int\limits_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{x^2+2x+2}\right)'\sin{(7x)}{\rm d}x
$$
On the left everything goes to $0$, and on the right, if you calculate the derivative explicitly, you can show the integral  absolutely converges, thus the LHS converges.